# editing layout and functionalities of Activity page in Redmine Circle theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have been working on editing Activity page of Redmine Circle theme. I have added a javascript plugin to get a timeline. The timeline is showing activities along with the date and time, however, date without activity is also visible in the timeline. The reason behind this could be the activity map in redmine.rb where activity is defined for other functionality that are not declared in the index.html.erb file of activities file of redmine.

```
    Redmine::Activity.map do |activity|
     activity.register :issues, :class_name => %w(Issue Journal)
     activity.register :changesets
     activity.register :news
     activity.register :documents, :class_name => %w(Document Attachment)
     activity.register :files, :class_name => 'Attachment'
     activity.register :wiki_edits,:class_name => 'WikiContent::Version', :default =>         false
     activity.register :messages, :default => false
     activity.register :time_entries, :default => false
    end
```

Now, the question is how can I fix the problem without editing redmine.rb file?

Comment: ami to jani na , ki answer hobe